# pass value to iframe on popover using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I have written a code to show popover iframe on hover a link. Now I want to pass the link value to that iframe window on popover. How can I do that?
Here is my code

```html
<a href="#" class="show-pop-iframe btn btn-default " data-placement="vertical" id="sample" value="email@domain.com">email@domain.com </a>
<a href="#" class="show-pop-iframe btn btn-default " data-placement="vertical" id="sample1" value="email1@domain1.com">email1@domain1.com </a>
<div id="auto"></div>
```

```js
(function(){
    var settings = {
        trigger:'hover',
        title:'Send Mail To User',
        content:'<p>This is webui popover demo.</p><p>just enjoy it and have fun !</p>',
        width:auto,                     
        multi:true,                     
        closeable:false,
        style:'',
        delay:300,
        padding:true,
        backdrop:false
    };

    function initPopover(){                 
        var iframeSettings = {  
            width:500,
            height:350,
            closeable:true,
            padding:false,
            type:'iframe',                      
            url:'http://localhost/live/liveuser.php'
        };              

        $('a.show-pop-iframe').webuiPopover('destroy').webuiPopover(
            $.extend({},settings,iframeSettings)
        );
    }

    initPopover();
})();
```

Comment: is this issue resolved?

Comment: no. @Parag Bhayani

Comment: Okay will try tomorrow... Remind me of if I forgot... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function initPopover(){                 
    var iframeSettings = {  
        width:500,
        height:350,
        closeable:true,
        padding:false,
        type:'iframe'
    };              

    $('a.show-pop-iframe').webuiPopover('destroy');
    $.each($('a.show-pop-iframe'), function (key, element) { 
        var url = 'http://localhost/live/liveuser.php';
        url += '?' + encodeURI($(element).attr("value")); // You will get link value in url
        webuiPopover($.extend({url: url},settings,iframeSettings));
    }
}
```